# how the methods of wrapped object are called using smart pointer

Tags: c++, implementation, smart-pointers

The question based on [implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15351/Implementing-a-simple-smart-pointer-in-c) of SP

```
class RC
{
    private:
    int count; // Reference count

    public:
    void AddRef()
    {
        // Increment the reference count
        count++;
    }

    int Release()
    {
        // Decrement the reference count and
        // return the reference count.
        return --count;
    }
};

template < typename T > class SP
{
private:
    T*    pData;       // pointer
    RC* reference; // Reference count

public:
    SP() : pData(0), reference(0) 
    {
        // Create a new reference 
        reference = new RC();
        // Increment the reference count
        reference->AddRef();
    }

    SP(T* pValue) : pData(pValue), reference(0)
    {
        // Create a new reference 
        reference = new RC();
        // Increment the reference count
        reference->AddRef();
    }

    SP(const SP<T>& sp) : pData(sp.pData), reference(sp.reference)
    {
        // Copy constructor
        // Copy the data and reference pointer
        // and increment the reference count
        reference->AddRef();
    }

    ~SP()
    {
        // Destructor
        // Decrement the reference count
        // if reference become zero delete the data
        if(reference->Release() == 0)
        {
            delete pData;
            delete reference;
        }
    }

    T& operator* ()
    {
        return *pData;
    }

    T* operator-> ()
    {
        return pData;
    }

    SP<T>& operator = (const SP<T>& sp)
    {
        // Assignment operator
        if (this != &sp) // Avoid self assignment
        {
            // Decrement the old reference count
            // if reference become zero delete the old data
            if(reference->Release() == 0)
            {
                delete pData;
                delete reference;
            }

            // Copy the data and reference pointer
            // and increment the reference count
            pData = sp.pData;
            reference = sp.reference;
            reference->AddRef();
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Suppose I have a `class Person`:

```
class Person
{
    int age;
    char* pName;

    public:
        Person(): pName(0),age(0)
        {
        }
        Person(char* pName, int age): pName(pName), age(age)
        {
        }
        ~Person()
        {
        }

        void Display()
        {
            printf("Name = %s Age = %d \n", pName, age);
        }
        void Shout()
        {
            printf("Ooooooooooooooooo",);
        } 
};
```

For he following `main` :

```
void main()
{
    SP p(new Person("Scott", 25));
    p->Display();
}
```

Why is it possible to call `p->Display();`?
Because `T*    pData;` is place before `RC` in the `SP`?

Comment: It's because of how the arrow operator is overloaded. If you have an expression `a->b`, and `a` is an object of a class with an overloaded arrow operator, then the result is `(a.operator->())->b`. That is, the arrow operator *chains* to its return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SP class has defined an `operator->`, which is what allows this to happen. It redirects the call to the other class. If you were to remove your `operator->` it would no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code equivalent that should help:

```
void main()
{
    SP p(new Person("Scott", 25));
    Person* person = p.operator->();
    person->Display();
}
```